# Response data is null in post data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I send a request to an API I get null but when I execute the same API in swagger I get the result back.

Below is my ASP.NET code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var data = new
            {
                test = "mydata"
            };

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("weburl.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

using (client)
{
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/test", data);

    if (res.ReasonPhrase == "OK")
    {
        res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resualt = res.Content;
            var res2 = await resualt.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModelApi>(res2);

            if (json.Succeed)
            {
                return json.Result;
            }
            else 
                return null;
        }
        else 
            return null;
    }
    else 
        return null;
}

HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/test", data);
```

res output :

> {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Vary: Accept-Encoding
>     Protect: SA
>     Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 11:20:16 GMT
>     Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dd54b1f82b2eb402e21bae199246157631535887216; expires=Mon, 02-Sep-19 11:20:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.myweb; HttpOnly
>     X-Powered-By: Huricane 11
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Server: cloudflare
>     CF-RAY: 453f961cb483bead-FRA
>     Connection: keep-alive
>     Content-Length: 0
>   }}

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: why is  Content-Length: 0 ?

Comment: Can you show us the result you get when calling from Swagger?

Comment: this is entered in swagger: {
  "test": "mydata"
}

Comment: response body in swagger: {
  "Succeed": true,
  "Result": "a89d94be-1ed5-43df-ad6f-d90c8cac6c1c"
}

Comment: response header in swagger : `cache-control: no-cache  cf-ray: 453f97fc369726ae-FRA  connection: keep-alive  content-encoding: gzip  content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8  date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 11:21:33 GMT  expires: -1  pragma: no-cache  protect: SA  server: cloudflare  transfer-encoding: chunked  vary: Accept-Encoding  x-powered-by: Huricane 11, ASP.NET`

Comment: What is the value of `res2`? can you also show the code for `JsonModelApi` class

Comment: res2 = null and  `public class JsonModelApi
        {
            public bool Succeed { get; set; }
            public string Result { get; set; }

       }`

Comment: Try `var res2 = await resualt.ReadAsAsync<string>();` instead of `ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: Here `var resualt = res.Content;` is resualt content length is 0.

Comment: Answers do not go in the question and I have rolled back your changes. If you want to add an answer, then add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code :

```
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("mywebapi");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

with added user-agent to HttpClient, I could result in content:

```
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This May Be its work :

```
var data = await MobileService.Client.InvokeApiAsync<RETURN TYPE, SEND_TYPE>($"api/test", 
HttpMethod_TYPE, null);
```